# Converting existing project to maven and run it in dev. mode in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I am converting open source project written using GWT 2.5.0 to maven, it is located in https://github.com/vitalidze/traccar-web It is working fine from command line and IntelliJ idea, which suits me well, but project author uses eclipse since it has special plugin along with UI designer, etc. (main project repo is https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-web).

So, I can't get it running in eclipse, no success at all. I can import it as maven project, then it is compiled well, putting javascript, png and html cache files under 'target/traccar-web-2.7-SNAPSHOT' folder. However, then it clears these files each time I run web application (issue in [GWT Maven - webapp files getting deleted when running in dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010533/gwt-maven-webapp-files-getting-deleted-when-running-in-dev-mode)).

My version of eclipse is 4.3 with latest google plugin for eclipse and m2e for maven integration (installed them on sunday 20th April).

Does anybody have any ideas how to get it working in eclipse? Maybe someone can point me where to look at. Any help is appreciated.

Best regards, Vitaly Litvak.

Answer (score 1):

Within the next few weeks, there will be a new release of the Google Plugin for Eclipse, which supports the import of a Maven App Engine project as a WTP project. Unfortunately, support for GWT is still some time off.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I have a working solution and will post it here once it's accepted by traccar-web project lead. It was a big pain to come to this solution while debugging google plugin by decompiled source code :) Thus, I think it would be very helpful if you share source code of plugin (on github AFAIK).